# Powering an Esp32 Project with USB-C and a Lithium Ion Battery

Tags: usb, esp32, battery

I have the Aitrip Esp32 Lite (see attached pinout image below).

Here's what I am wondering - the devboard has an on board charging receptacle (JST) for a lithium ion battery. Using the devboard's on-board usb-c port, I am able to charge the battery and, when usb-c cable is removed, the device is powered by the battery. All works great.

if I want to use a usb-c female port for POWER ONLY (see other attached picture), to where to I attach the positive and negative leads from the usb-c power?

Thank you in advance - I feel like this is a super nooby type question to be asking but, although I am quite familiar with using sensors and coding within the Arduino IDE and using libraries and so on, I can't seem to work out how power, batteries, voltage pins etc work together in projects like these... If someone can direct me to an appropriate tutorial or lesson online, I would be so grateful. I feel like I've searched the web high and low, but can't seem to find any user-friendly, ground-up lessons, essays, tutorials, or other learning resources to help me understand what I'm assuming is a fairly elementary subject...

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about programming so is in the wrong place. One of the other sites should be a better fit. Good luck https://stackexchange.com/sites

Answer (score 0):

If you want to power the ESP32 Lite development board solely through the USB-C female port without using the lithium-ion battery, you should connect the positive and negative terminals of the USB-C power to the corresponding pins on the ESP32 Lite board.